# Why do we need funcall in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, funcall

Why do we have to use `funcall` to call higher order functions in Common Lisp? For example, why do we have to use:

```
(defun foo (test-func args)
  (funcall test-func args))
```

instead of the simpler:

```
(defun bar (test-func args)
  (test-func args))
```

Coming from a procedural background, I'm a bit surprised by that since the languages I'm more used to (e.g. Python, C#) don't need the distinction. In particular, on the source level at least, the C# compiler transforms it to something like `func.invoke()`.

The only problem I see is that this would mean we couldn't call a global function `test-func` anymore because it'd be shadowed, but that's hardly a problem.

Comment: "Hardly a problem" is the crux of the matter. In practice, I find it hardly a problem to call funcall and would be inconvenienced if I had to choose creative/weird names for variables to avoid clashes with CAR, LIST, REST, etc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `funcall` would not be needed, but there are some lisps ([lisp-2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/850781) variants, such as Common Lisp) that separate the *variable name space* of the *function name space*. Lisp-1 variants (e.g. Scheme) do not make this distinction.

More specifically, in your case, `test-func` is in the variable name space.

```
(defun foo (test-func args)
  (funcall test-func args))
```

Therefore you need a construct that actually searches the function object associated with this variable in the variable name space. In Common Lisp this construct is `funcall`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/665673/62365).

Answer (score 23):

The majority of Lisps have **two namespaces** (functions and variables). A name is looked up in the function namespace when it appears as the first element in an S-expression, and in the variable namespace otherwise. This allows you to name your variables without worrying about whether they shadow functions: so you can name your variable `list` instead of having to mangle it into `lst`.

However, this means that when you store a function in a variable, you can't call it normally:

```
(setq list #'+) ; updates list in the variable namespace
(list 1 2 3) => (1 2 3) ; looks up list in the function namespace
```

Hence the need for [`funcall`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_funcal.htm) and [`apply`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm):

```
(funcall list 1 2 3) => 6 ; looks up list in the variable namespace
```

(Not all Lisps have two namespaces: Scheme is an example of a Lisp with just one namespace.)

Comment: Yes the advantage of not shadowing functions is nice, but on the other hand we get the special cases for functions.. well I assume since we don't have to worry about bracket positioning in lisp, we need other religious wars ;) Since you and Diego both answered my question nicely, I went with time as a tie-breaker and accepted diego's answer.

Answer (score -2):

In Common Lisp, each symbol can be associated with its [symbol-function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_1.htm#symbol-function) and its [symbol-value](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_5.htm#symbol-value), among other things. When reading a list, by default, Common Lisp interprets:

- arg1 as a function and so retrieves `test-func`'s `symbol-function`, which is undefined -- thus function `bar` doesn't work
- arg2 as something to be `eval`ed -- thus function `foo` retrieves `test-func`'s `symbol-value`, which, in your case, happens to be a function

Comment: this is not what a Common Lisp implementation does. You might want to read about lexical bindings.