# lisp: lambda scope

Tags: lisp

I want to implement `filter` function that would filter a list based on a condition

```
(defun filter (func xs)                                                          
  (mapcan                                                                        
    (lambda (x)                                                                  
      (when (func x) (list x))) xs ))
```

but I get an error:

```
*** - EVAL: undefined function FUNC
```

I thought that lambda should see `func`. How to pass `func` to `lambda` correctly?

I use [CLISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLISP).

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the function `REMOVE-IF-NOT` which does exactly this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want

```
(when (funcall func x) (list x))
```

instead of

```
(when (func x) (list x))
```

More information about function vs. variable namespace:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp-1_vs._Lisp-2#The_function_namespace
- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleNamespaceLisp
- [Why do we need funcall in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729549/why-do-we-need-funcall-in-lisp)

Comment: Just mentioning that `(func x)` tries to evaluate a function called `func` whereas `(funcall func x)` call a function called `func` with `x` as its argument.