# How to store a function in a variable in Lisp and use it

Tags: scheme, common-lisp, eval, first-class-functions, lisp-2

I want to store a function like `print` in a variable so that I can just type something short like `p`, e.g:
In `Scheme`:

```
(define print display)
(print "Hello world\n")
;; alternate way
(define print 'display)
((eval print) "Hello world\n")
```

The same approach does not seem to work in `Common Lisp`:

```
(defvar p 'print)
;;(print (type-of p))
(p "Hello world") ;; Attempt 1
((eval p) "Hello world") ;; >> Attempt 2
((eval (environment) p) "Hello world") ;; Attempt 3
```

I'm getting this error with `Attempt 1` above:

```
*** - EVAL: undefined function P
```

And this with `Attempt 2` and `3` in `Clisp`:

```
*** - EVAL: (EVAL (ENVIRONMENT) P) is not a function name; try using a 
            symbol instead
*** - EVAL: (EVAL P) is not a function name; try using a symbol instead
```

And with `gcl`:

```
Error: (EVAL P) is invalid as a function.
Error: (EVAL (ENVIRONMENT) P) is invalid as a function.
```

So:

- What does `try using a symbol` mean? `p` is definitely a `symbol`; false positive?
- What's up with `eval`? Doesn't the evaluation of `p` yield the procedure `print`?
- I thought `Lisp` procedures were `first class objects`. Why is `Attempt 1` not working like in `Scheme`?

**EDIT**
(Moved from a comment below)

I was wondering why `(setf (symbol-function 'p) #'print)` won't work this way
`(setf (symbol-function 'p) 'print)`. I get the following(not so helpful) error:

```
*** - SYSTEM::%PUTD: PRINT is not a function ;; CLisp
Error: PRINT is not of type LIST. ;; Gcl
```

I know that the sharp sign(`#`) is supposed to disambiguate between a function and a variable
with the same name but in this case, there's only one `print`, the function.

Also, why won't it work with `defvar` instead of `setf` like so:

```
(defvar (symbol-function 'p) #'print)
```

yet `defvar` and `setf` both assign values to a variable.
The associated error is:

```
*** - DEFVAR: non-symbol (SYMBOL-FUNCTION 'P) cannot be a variable ;; Clisp
Error: (SYMBOL-FUNCTION (QUOTE P)) is not of type SYMBOL. ;; Gcl
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we need funcall in lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729549/why-do-we-need-funcall-in-lisp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common Lisp is a ["Lisp-2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578574/what-is-the-difference-between-lisp-1-and-lisp-2).  Among other things, the first position in a function call is evaluated in the "function namespace".  In your case, the symbol `p` names a variable, not a function.

This works better:

```lisp
(defvar p 'print)

(funcall p "Hello world")
```

Or possibly, but you probably don't want to do this:

```lisp
(setf (symbol-function 'p) #'print)

(p "Hello world")
```

Comment: Given that this might be for some local scope, I'd also point out `flet` and `labels`.

Answer (score 6):

Common Lisp has a separate namespace for functions, which makes operation like this more verbose than with Scheme. If you would like similar to **top level** `(define p display)` in CL you should make a macro:

```
(defmacro defun-alias (name original-name)
   `(setf (symbol-function ',name) #',original-name))
```

Which works as this:

```
(defun-alias pc princ)
(pc "Hello") ; prints hello
```

Unlike Scheme `define` this will only overwrite a global binding. Thus:

```
(flet ((test (x) (+ x x))) 
   (defun-alias test +)
   (test 10))
```

will set global definition of `#'test` to `#'+` and return 20. eg. it works like `defun`.

Comment: I like the macro, it comes close to `Scheme`'s `define`

Answer (score 5):

To complement the other good answers with direct answers to your questions:

> What does try using a symbol mean? p is definitely a symbol; false positive?

Read the error messages literally: `(EVAL (ENVIRONMENT) P)` and `(EVAL P)` (unevaluated) are not symbols, but lists. In Common Lisp, the car of a form is not evaluated.

> What's up with eval? Doesn't the evaluation of p yield the procedure print?

`eval` is never called by your code (see previous answer). Even if it were, the result would be the `symbol-value` of the symbol `print`, not the `symbol-function`/`fdefinition`.

> I thought Lisp procedures were first class objects. Why is Attempt 1 not working like in Scheme?

This has nothing to do with functions (I think the Common Lisp standard does not use the term "procedures" as the Scheme standards do.) being first class objects. This works in Common Lisp:

```
(let ((p #'print))
  (funcall p "hello world"))
```

**Edit**:

Answers to the extra questions:

> I was wondering why `(setf (symbol-function 'p) #'print)` won't work this way
>   `(setf (symbol-function 'p) 'print)`.

It's not really true that "the sharp sign(#) is supposed to disambiguate between a function and a variable with the same name", as you write later. `'print` expands to `(quote print)`, so it evaluates to the symbol `print` instead of its value as a variable. `#'print` expands to `(function print)`, so it evaluates to the value of the function cell of the symbol `print` instead. Whether `print` currently has a value as a variable is completely irrelevant to what `#'print` evaluates to.

Setting `(symbol-function 'p)` to the symbol `print` obviously won't make `p` call the function `print` because the symbol `print` is not the same as the function bound to the symbol `print`.

> Also, why won't it work with defvar instead of setf like so:

```
(defvar (symbol-function 'p) #'print)
```

> yet defvar and setf both assign values to a variable.

`setf` assigns values to places. The term `(symbol-function 'p)` denotes the place that is the function cell of the symbol `p`.

`defvar` defines new global variables. Its first argument needs to be a symbol that names the variable and can not be any kind of place.

Comment: And, what is the answer to the question in the comment?

Comment: Why aren't `car`s of forms evaluated?

Comment: @Segfault: Here's the relevant section of the standard: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abab.htm. So actually, there are two valid types for the car of a form, symbols or lambda expressions. This would work: `((lambda (s) (funcall p s)) "hello world")`.

Comment: @Segfault: Regarding your questions in the comments to LarsBrinkhoff's answer, please clarify what exactly is still unclear to you.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Segfault: I've added answers to the extra questions.

Comment: I'm tempted to ask why said "it's not really true" but I'll try to find that out for myself. That's a beautiful answer, btw.

Comment: @Segfault: I'll give you a short answer to that anyway. The Sharpsign is not activating a special mode of the Single-Quote reader macro. Single-Quote `'` and Sharpsign Single-Quote `#'` are two completely different reader macros. See this two sections of the standard: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dc.htm and http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhb.htm.

Comment: @Segfault I'm surprised this answer isn't the accepted one. I thought it'd be the most helpful one, most detailed and directly specific.

Comment: I must confess, I was swayed by the votes. And yes @WillNess , it was the most helpful. I felt as if the others just answered and never checked back. It seems wrong to change it almost a week later though.

Comment: @Segfault no, it's OK to change it whenever you feel like it's warranted to do so. We're supposed to accept the most helpful answer on SO, that's in the FAQ. :)